# When I try to put the JButton into the JList,the JBtton in the JList can't show the correct name

Tags: java, swing, jlist

```
    import javax.swing.JList.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class test {
        static JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        //return
        static DefaultListModel lt=new DefaultListModel();
        static JList<JButton> jlt=new JList<JButton>();
        static ArrayList <JRadioButton> arr=new ArrayList<JRadioButton>();
    
        public static void main(String [] args){
            String[] arr1={"woill","dkdok","dmkm"};

            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                arr.add(new JRadioButton(arr1[j]));
            }
        
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                lt.addElement(arr.get(i));
            }

            jlt.setModel(lt);
            frame.add(jlt);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

When I try to put the JButton into the JList, it doesn't show the correct name !

Why ?

[image: the wrong image: [enter image description here][1]]

Comment: Why do you want to put a `JRadioButton` in a `JList`? A `JList` is a control for selecting entries in a list, how do you plan on selecting a `JRadioButton` and why? Maybe you don't want to use a `JList` and instead place the `JRadioButton` on the panel directly.

Comment: A JList (and JTable) are used to display data not components. The data is stored in the model and a renderer is used to paint the data. The default renderer just invokes the toString() method of the Object added to the model which is why you see what you see. A JList does NOT respond to mouse events and therefore you can't click on a radio button so you should not be using a JList for this.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are thinking along the lines of a ComboBox with a ListCell Renderer, as described here?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable

Comment: Thanks for your response. The data you offer is what I need.